# Identifying Windows Active Directory Connection - Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, active-directory

Is there a way from within a Windows 8 store app (C#) to either identify that the OS is Windows 8 Pro or Enterprise edition?  Can you also check to see if the OS has the capability to connect to an AD domain?

I have found other posts saying that it isn't possible to find the version of Windows, and the posts suggest checking for capabilities.  I have not been able to find any information on how to check if the user is connected to a domain or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [UserInformation.GetDomainNameAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.getdomainnameasync.aspx) to determine if the user is part of a domain.  The app must declare the [Enterprise Authentication app capability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx).

To determine if you are on Pro, you might be able to call [GetNativeSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms724340.aspx) and figure it out from the processor architecture.